# Access Map with in a wrapper class in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

Apex Class:

```
public class thewrapperClass {
        @AuraEnabled 
        public List<String> theList{ get; set;}
         @AuraEnabled 
        public Map<String,String> theMap { get; set;}
}
```

I'm returning the wrapperlist from apex

Js controller:

```
component.set("theList",wrapperlist );
```

Component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.theList}" var="obj">

</aura:iteration>
```

I can see "theMap" in the JSON which is being returned from the apex, but how do I access key and value with in the component along with the wrapperclass as a whole.

Comment: If you know key name, then you can access it my like {!obj.theMap.key}

Comment: No I don't know the key name, the map is dynamically generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access map values in wrapper class.Some thing like this.
I have implemented simple wrapper class.For understanding , simply I added few  values for map.

**testWrapper.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="wrapperDisplay" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadData}"/>
 <aura:attribute name="lstKey" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="fullMap" type="map"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrapperList" type="object"/>
<h1 style="font-size:25px;">{!v.wrapperList.headerMsg}</h1> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.lstKey}" var="key" >
    <c:mapEntryChild map="{!v.fullMap}" key="{!key}"/>
</aura:iteration>
 </aura:component>
```

---

```
 ({
loadData: function(component, event, helper) {
    var arrayOfMapKeys = [];
  //call apex class method
  var action = component.get('c.initMethod');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    //store state of response
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
      //set response value in wrapperList attribute on component.
      var StoreResponse = response.getReturnValue().themap;
            component.set('v.fullMap', StoreResponse);

            for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
                arrayOfMapKeys.push(singlekey);
            }
              component.set('v.lstKey', arrayOfMapKeys);

      component.set('v.wrapperList', response.getReturnValue());
    } });$A.enqueueAction(action); }})
```

---

**mapEntryChild.cmp**

```
  <aura:component >
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="map" type="map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="key" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="string"/>
       <p>{!v.key} --- {!v.value}</p>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
 ({
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var key = component.get("v.key");
    var map = component.get("v.map");

    // set the values of map to the value attribute 
    // to get map values in lightning component use "map[key]" syntax. 
    component.set("v.value" , map[key]);
}})
```

---

Serverside controller:

```
  public class wrapperDisplay {
    @AuraEnabled
public static wrapperClass initMethod(){

    map<string,string>mymap=new map<string,string>();
    wrapperClass returnwrapperClass = new  wrapperClass ();        
    returnwrapperClass.headerMsg = 'Map example in wrapper';
    mymap.put('key1','test1');
    mymap.put('key2','test2');  
    returnwrapperClass.themap=mymap;
    return returnwrapperClass;    
}


public class wrapperClass{
    @AuraEnabled public String headerMsg {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public map<string,string> themap{get;set;}
}}
```

Application:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
  <c:testWrapper />
 </aura:application>
```

Comment: I have changed my logic to return list of objects instead. I haven't tested your logic but seems like it should work.

Comment: I have tested it in my personal org .It works

Answer (score -1):

You can create a map iterator component that can display value with respect to the key field. Its the best approach I found while iterating over maps.

Links: http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/01/13/iterate-map-values-lightning-component/